# Circular dependency in Scala

Tags: scala, circular-dependency

I have a Scala project A that has an interface (abstract class) I, the implementations of it, and a reference to project B (B.jar). A is packaged with `publish-local` to be compiled into jar file and stored in a .ivy directory. 
Project B, in turn, uses the I interface in project B; it compiled into a jar and into a .ivy directory.

Here come some design questions in Scala:

- Is this a circular dependency as A refers to B when B refers to A?
- If the first question is an issue, I guess the simplistic solution is to extract an interface I from A, make it another project to be referenced both by A and B. Isn't this overkill to have a project that has only one interface? Or it's just OK as B references only one class file in A. What's the best practice in Scala?

Comment: no its not a circular dependency, well it is on paper. but not on the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

There are times when a so called cyclic dependency can reduce lines of code and so cannot be discouraged as  `bad practice' de facto.
It all depends on the context of the project. 
You need answers to questions like ,

1. Do the projects needs to be in different libraries at all ?
2. If so can we consider using a DI framework ? eg Spring , Guice etc

Then because it is scala you dont really need a `framework` per say to implement this.

Consider the following example ,

```
  class IdentityCard(val id: String, val manufacturerCompany: String, person: => Person)
  class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, icard: => IdentityCard)

  lazy val iCard = new IdentityCard("123","XYZ",person)
  lazy val person:Person = new Person("som","bhattacharyya",iCard)
```

These two classes can be in separate jars and still compile and work together with less code.
Note, we are using a call-by-name for the dependencies being passed in. Also we are doing lazy initialization of the variables so they are not evaluated till they are accessed. This allows us to `forward-reference` ie. using a variable first and defining later.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give "best practice" advice without more specifics. If "project B" is tightly coupled with project A, they should probably both be in the same project, but in different sub-projects/sub-modules. The interface B uses could also be its own sub-project to remove the circle.

sbt and maven support this, [here's the sbt docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html).